# Clipping problem adding notes to create chords

Tags: c++, audio

I tried to create chords by simply adding notes which I load into 4 buffers. My problem is clipping. Doing some tests with **Audacity** and using the same samples does not happen. I can't understand how Audacity itself solved this kind of problem.

Below is an excerpt in pseudocode to try to make my problem understood.

As you can see from the image link, only in some places the problem exists, the rest is summed up correctly as audacity does.
The two graphs above are the result of Audacity, the ones below, the result of my sum.

Thank you

https://ibb.co/3kptCFd

```
// buffer notes. Are short values (from -32768 to 32767)
short *bfn[4];

// creation of the 4 buffers which contain the notes
for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    bfn[i] = new short[44100];

// buffer chords
short *chords = new short[44100];

// chord creation cycle
for(int i=0; i<44100;i++)
{
    chords[i] = bfn[0][i];
    chords[i]+= bfn[1][i];
    chords[i]+= bfn[2][i];
    chords[i]+= bfn[3][i];
}
```

Comment: If your chord consists of N notes then then each note value should be divided by N before summing, no?

Comment: thanks for the tip, but sadly I don't think Audacity does that way. Comparing my sums with those of Audacity, see the figure at the link, they are the same except for the points near the maximum and minimum values possible by the short type.

Comment: 1000 thanks anyway, i solved it by myself